# Meter and service panel separate from house

Tags: electrical-panel

I am renovating a farmhouse that has been unlived in for 8-10 years and has had power disconnected for that amount of time as well.  The previous owner in order to test a well without changing/fixing the wiring inside the house had a meter and main service panel placed on a pole 20' from the house.  It has a single grounding rod at the pole.  There is currently no line running from this to the house.  When I reconnect the house to power will I need to move the main to the house?  Do I just have to reconnect to the old service panel (In the middle of the house) or will I have to replace/move the panel to where the power will be connected to the house.  Will I run a new set of grounding rods?

Comment: Was the house originally set up for overhead service with a mast sticking out the roof, or for underground service with the wires entering via a conduit?  What make and model is the old service panel?

Answer (score 1):

This is a question that only your AHJ (Authority Having Jurisdiction, aka local inspector) can answer for you. There is no specific NATIONAL code violation in doing so, but there could very well be local codes prohibiting this kind of setup, having to do with life / safety issues, fire fighter access, maybe even utility requirements.

If it IS permitted, you would NOT install a new set of ground rods at the house, you would run the EGC (Electrical Grounding Conductor) from your service entrance ground connection back to any local "sub panel" that you install at the house. Likewise with your Neutral conductor, and in this case, because the main is where the Neutral is ALREADY bonded, you would NOT bond the neutral again at the house.

Comment: I think you would also need grounding rods at the house, unless theAHJ waives it for being only 20'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a illustration of your situation from one of my continuing ed. classes, along with all the necessary code references.
[image]

Let's call the main building your pole drop. Building 2 is your existing farm house and Building 1 is the well. Take note that your grounding system in all of your buildings must be fed back to your first means if disconnect and attached there. Also note in Building 2 you must install a separate ground bus isolated from your neutrals. You can tie in your grounding electrode conductor to that bus and feed it back to your main breaker. If you have metal piping in an old house, that makes an excellent ground and if you want to drive a rod you can do that too. Also if your well has a steel casing, I would tie it into the ground system also.

The main thing to remember is that all of the electrodes that are available must be bonded together to form a grounding electrode system.